# Self-hosted web analytics tools

Tags: analytics, self-hosted

I'm looking for a self-hosted web analytics software.

Basically, something like Woopra or Google Analytics but installed "on prem" instead of on cloud.

Currently seen PiWik, HaveAMint, any others out there anyone would recommend?

Comment: might not be exactly what you are looking for, but Whatagraph does reports based on Google Analytics data.. might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

A new one to add to the list:

I'm working on Plausible Analytics, a simple, open-source, lightweight (< 1 KB) and privacy-friendly web analytics alternative to Google Analytics. You can [self-host it on your own server too](https://plausible.io/self-hosted-web-analytics).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/). It can be a good alternative to Google Analytics and it's open source.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same recently.
HaveAMint was discontinued meanwhile. As was IBMs Unica Net Insight

I recommend:

1) [Matomo](https://matomo.org/) ( formerly Piwik ) - it's free to use but has Pro Upgrade

2) [Angelfish Analytics](http://analytics.angelfishstats.com/) - they use an embedded database

3) [IBM Tealeaf cx](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS2MBL_9.0.2/CXReleaseNotes/CX/cxReleaseNotes/TealeafCXPlatform_20.html) - successor to Unica

4) [Webtrends Analytics](https://www.webtrends.com/?dcsref=www.webtrends.de&dcssta=301) - probably one of the biggest on the market

5) [Countly](https://count.ly/mobile-analytics) - they IoT support for IoT

6) [CustomerEngagePro](http://www.customerengagepro.com/)

7) [Rakam](https://rakam.io/)

This list is unordered, the numbers are not priorities. Hope this helps

Comment: We use Angelfish at my company, I recommend it.

Tealeaf is/was more of a session recording & playback tool than a web analytics tool, CX = Customer eXperience