# Open source web analytics tracker

Tags: open-source, analytics

Prior to building such a thing, I'm trying to find an open source javascript based web analytics tracker for the purpose of tracking marketing automation campaigns:

- visitor tracking
- time on site
- document downloads
- videos watched
- form submissions

I've found several "self hosted" versions of web analytics platforms but nothing that suggests there is a recommended open source analytics tracker.

*Similar question but not limited to open source: [Self-hosted web analytics tools](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20336/self-hosted-web-analytics-tools)*

Comment: Not tried (I don't use analytics on my sites), but [Matomo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matomo) (previously known as Piwik) is Open Source, well-known, and often recommended.

Comment: Are you certain that you must have [tag:opensource], or would [tag:gratis] do? The latter is likely to generate more answers.